# Highest common factor of two polynomials

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I have $$f(x) = x^3-2x^2-5x+6,\quad g(x)=x^2-2x-3$$

Then $f(x) = x(x^2-2x-3) +(-2x+6)$

So $hcf(f(x),g(x))=hcf((x^2-2x-3),(-2x+6))$

$x^2-2x-3=(-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2})(-2x+6)+0$

So $hcf(f(x),g(x))=hcf((-2x+6),(0)) = 0$

Is this correct? If yes, then is the $0$ representing polynomials of degree $0$ or polynomials $h(x)$ such that $h(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to zero, the highest common factor is the one you had just before.  Here $2x-6=2(x-3)$ and $x-3$ is the highest common factor of the first polynomials.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting seriously confused.

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 5 x  + 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 5 x  + 6 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) } +  \left(   - 2 x  + 6 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(   - 2 x  + 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  -  x  + 2 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 2 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 5 x  + 6 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =  \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 5 x  + 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x  + 3 \right)  $$

Answer (score 0):

The two polynomials satisfy $gcd(f,g)=1$, because $g(x)=(x+1)(x-3)$, and both $-1$ and $3$ are not a root of $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-5x+6$, i.e., both $(x+1)$ and $(x-3)$ are not a factor of $f$. So $1$ is the highest common factor.

Edit: The new polynomial now is $f(x)=x^3-2x^2-5x+6$. This changes the answer to $gcd(f,g)=x-3$.

Comment: I see, so where in my method did I go wrong

Comment: We do not have $hcf(f(x),g(x))=hcf((x^2-2x-3),(-2x+6))=(x+3)$.

Comment: So how would one use Euclid's Algorithm to obtain the hcf?

Comment: Just do the computation right. You claim that $f(x)=x(x^2-2x-3)+(-2x+6)=x^3-2x^2-5x+6$, which is wrong.

Comment: I don't see how its wrong, isn't the LHS equivalent to the RHS?

Comment: Well, it contradicts the first line, where it says $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-5x+6$. Your computation gives $x^3-2x^2-5x+6$, which is not the same.

Comment: Ah that was a typo, it should read $f(x)=x^3-2x^2-5x+6$, apologies. Does this change your answer?

Comment: In your first line it is $g(x)=(x+1)(x-3)$ and the edit has made $3$ a root of $f$.